# Making an inherited field not required in child content type definition

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, content-type, elements-xml

I am creating field definitions and content types through xml in my SPFX solution and require that a field is optional by default but required in a child content type. For example I have a "News" content type that is based off of the Site Page Content type, it has an author field attached to it, this field is optional. I also have a "Headline News" content type that inherits from the "News" content type, this child content type should inherit the author field with the difference that it should be a required field.

I have included my code below:

**Field Definition**

```
<Field ID="{cfbe9de0-b59c-4376-9bbb-305b6a140b18}" Name="NewsAuthor" Type="User" UserSelectionMode="0" Required="FALSE" DisplayName="Author" />
```

**News Content Type**

```
<ContentType ID="0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C41180079f63c596797418dac194162166a56e4" Name="News" Inherits="TRUE">
  <FieldRefs>
    <FieldRef ID="{cfbe9de0-b59c-4376-9bbb-305b6a140b18}" Name="NewsAuthor" Required="FALSE" />
    ...
  </FieldRefs>
</ContentType>
```

**Headline News Content Type**

```
<ContentType ID="0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C41180079f63c596797418dac194162166a56e401" Name="Headline News" Inherits="TRUE">
  <FieldRefs>
    <FieldRef ID="{cfbe9de0-b59c-4376-9bbb-305b6a140b18}" Name="NewsAuthor" Required="TRUE" />
  </FieldRefs>
</ContentType>
```

The issue is that it is leaving the Author field as optional and not taking in the `Required="TRUE"` in the child content type. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

Since I am not finding a way to do this I am currently attempting to remove the author field from my **Headline News** content type but this doesn't seem to work either...

My idea is if i can remove it then I can create a new field for this specific content type and add it there. Any ideas on why this might not be working?

Here is the link defining how the RemoveFieldRef should work and I don't see any issues with how im doing it...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/removefieldref-element-contenttype

```
<ContentType ID="0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C41180079f63c596797418dac194162166a56e401" Name="Headline News" Inherits="TRUE">
  <FieldRefs>
    <RemoveFieldRef ID="{cfbe9de0-b59c-4376-9bbb-305b6a140b18}" Name="NewsAuthor" />
  </FieldRefs>
</ContentType>
```

**UPDATE 2**

It seems for the **RemoveFieldRef** you can't use `Inherit="TRUE"` from the Content Type... But when I don't inherit I lose all the parent fields and the site stops treating new pages with this Content Type as pages. Also if it doesn't inherit any of the fields there would be no point in using the **RemoveFieldRef** I'm a little confused as to the logic in this...